# Why i am not getting the value of the variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :testitout 
goto:eof

set "SERVER[1]=server1.oll.is.server1.com"
set "SERVER[2]=server2.cyl.is.anydom.com"

:testitout
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,2) DO (

ping  !SERVER[%%i]! -n 1 -4 | find /i "TTL=">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ping %!SERVER[%%i]!% failure
    echo ping %%SERVER[%%i]%% failure
    echo ping %!SERVER[%%i]!% failure
    echo ping !SERVER[%%i]! failure

) else ( 

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('Cscript %WINDIR%\\System32\\Printing_Admin_Scripts\\en-US\\Prnmngr.vbs -l -s %%SERVER[%%i]%%') do (
 set str1=%%f
if /i not "!str1:Server name=!"=="!str1!" (
  set str1=!str1:Server name =!
  if /i not "!str1:Server name=!"=="!str1!" (
  echo | set /p="   "
  ) else (
  echo | set /p="!str1! "
  )
)

if /i not "!str1:Printer name=!"=="!str1!" (
  set str1=!str1:Printer name =!
  if /i not "!str1:Printer name=!"=="!str1!" (
  echo | set /p="   "
  ) else (
  echo | set /p="!str1! "
  )
)
if /i not "!str1:Share name=!"=="!str1!" (
  set str1=!str1:Share name =!
  if /i not "!str1:Share name=!"=="!str1!" (
  echo | set /p="   "
  ) else (
  echo | set /p="!str1! "
  )
)

if /i not "!str1:Driver name=!"=="!str1!" (
  set str1=!str1:Driver name =!
  if /i not "!str1:Driver name=!"=="!str1!" (
  echo | set /p="   "
  ) else (
  echo | set /p="!str1! "
  )
)

if /i not "!str1:Port name=!"=="!str1!" (
  set str1=!str1:Port name =!
  if /i not "!str1:Port name=!"=="!str1!" (
  echo | set /p="   "
  ) else (
  echo !str1!
  )
)

) 
)
)
```

output :

```
ping  failure
ping %SERVER[1]% failure
ping  failure
ping  failure
ping  failure
ping %SERVER[2]% failure
ping  failure
ping  failure
```

I am tried syntaxes with echo (%SERVER[%%i]%, !SERVER[%%i]! etc ) but why can't get the value of the array variable  echoed..
it should show **ping servername failure**
Please help

**EDIT :** 
it was working fine with `!SERVER[%%i]!` until i added the `:testitout` function so that i can capture the output inside the script in a file like `call :testitout > output.txt` but after i added the function `:testitout` it stopped working.

Comment: try with ` echo ping !SERVER[%%i]! failure`

Comment: yes , it was working fine with `!SERVER[%%i]!` until i added the `:testitout` function so that i can capture the output inside the script in a file `call :testitout  > output.txt` but after i added the function `:testitout` it stops working

Comment: is there any other way to capture the output other than running the script on the command line like `scriptname > outputfile.txt`

Comment: OK, it looks simple now i understand batch functions are not like other programming languages... it like a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `set` clauses after the `call`. Should be the other way around:

```
set "SERVER[1]=server1.oll.is.server1.com"
set "SERVER[2]=server2.cyl.is.anydom.com"

call :testitout
goto eof
```

Because `set` runs only after the `call`, you are not getting any value for your parameters.